# How can I fix this Mysql login?

Tags: windows, mysql, windows-server-2012-r2, command-line-interface, mysql8

I have installed MYSQL community edition on Windows server, I also added the Environment variable to execute the mysql command.

**The scenario is**: When I try to connect to mysql using the CMD I get the error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

If I try to connect using Powershell and Mysql Workbench it does work.

How can I connect using the CMD?

Comment: The most obvious when you get an error regarding incorrect credentials is to check and confirm that you're using the correct credentials, possibly by resetting the MySQL user account. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/creating-accounts.html https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/assigning-passwords.html

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, when I use the same credentials on Mysql Workbench and Powershell it does work the connection to the database, ONLY in CMD is not working